# Splash screen with activity indicator works fine in iOS6 but not in iOS5

Tags: ios5, ios6, splash-screen

I would like to show a splash screen view with activity indicator to load some information from a server before entering inside my app. Below is how I do it:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    FeedViewController *feedViewController = [[FeedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FeedViewController" bundle:nil];

    MenuViewController *menuViewController=[[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:feedViewController];

    IIViewDeckController* deckController =  [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:self.navController leftViewController:menuViewController rightViewController:nil];
    deckController.panningMode=IIViewDeckNoPanning;
    deckController.panningView=menuViewController.view;
    self.window.rootViewController = deckController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // show splash screen until data is loaded
    SplashScreenViewController *controller = [[SplashScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashScreenViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [feedViewController presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];

     return YES;
}
```

In FeedViewController.m, I did something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // load data from a server

    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissSplashScreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

This code works very well with iOS6, but when I tested it with iOS5 the splash screen with activity indicator spinning just does not disappear. I suspect I might implement a splash screen in a wrong way. (But I don't understand why this works in iOS6?)

Comment: If you just remove `dismissSplashScreen` part, is it showing in iOS5? Also try this `[deckController presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];`.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem myself by using a bool variable to check whether the splash screen should be shown. The code for showing the splash screen is moved to `viewDidLoad` of FeedViewController instead.

This approach seems to work well for both iOS5 and iOS6.